# Pass member to non-static function without ref

Tags: c#

I have this construct in a class in a couple setters:

```
this.RaiseUnselected(this.property);
this.property = value;
this.RaiseSelected(this.property);
```

To clean up my class I extracted this into a method like:

```
    private void SetProperty(IType target, IType value)
    {
        this.RaiseUnselected(target);
        target = value;
        this.RaiseSelected(target);
    }
```

This caused a couple unit tests to fail.  As you can probably see the issue is that the `target` is passed by value and the setting does not get reflected back to the `this.property` passed as `target`.

I fixed it by changing the function to

```
private void SetProperty(ref IType target, IType value)
```

but I'm not a big fan of using `ref` if possible.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `ref` is meant for; there is nothing wrong with using it here.